# Connect MySQL Using TcpClient

Tags: c#, mysql

Is it possible to use TcpClient to connect to a database?

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3306);
client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
//Missing Code, don't know how to proceed...
```

Comment: What is it you are you trying to do once connected? Can you not just use the [libraries they supply](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/).

Comment: @Phylogenesis Ya, i know the ordinary way to connect to MySQL. However, I'm trying to create something similar to "MySql.Data.dll". Something like traditional way (not sure what it is, really trying very hard now.)....

Comment: There isn't a simple answer to your question then. Yes it is *possible*. No it is not *easy*. You will have to spend a significant amount of time studying the protocol to even begin to attempt this.